# How to make new web page for each unique ID with Django

Tags: python, html, django

I have a dataset where each unique ID needs its own webpage with a set of visualizations. I want to generate a new webpage iteratively for each unique ID. I am doing this with Django. Is anyone aware of any examples or guidance on how to do this?

Comment: Could you be more clear. What does 'make a new web page' mean? Maybe you could give an example of how a user would see this. Or, how this might work in practice.

Comment: You should check [DetailView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1):

you might want to try django's class based details view. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#detailview

suppose you have a model named Person.

```
class Person(models.Model):
   id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
   name = modes.CharField(max_length=20)
```

if you want to see details of each person for different user id use Django's class-based views. things can be done using function too. but it's easier to use generic views.

in views.py:

```
from django.views.generic.detail import DetailView

class PersonDetails(DetailView):
   model = Person
   contex_object_name = 'person'
   template_name = '<app_template_directory>/<template>.html'
```

you don't need to define template_name if you have already an HTML page in your "app directory" as [model]_detail.html. In our case person/person_detail.html

urls.py:

```
app_name = 'person'
urlpatterns = [
    path('person/<int:pk>/', PersonDetails.as_view(), name='details')]
```

for a person with id 1, http://localhost:8000/person/1/  will generate a page with details of that person.